# Haki Hardness Grades?

Tags: one-piece

I've been getting caught up on *One Piece* and I noticed that in chapter 837 (Luffy vs Commander Cracker) page 16, Luffy states that Cracker's Busoshoku was the hardest thing he came across.

[image: Luffy stating Cracker's hardest Busoshoku]

At first glance, I am instantly reminded of power levels in *Dragon Ball Z*.

My question is if a sort of grading system is in place determining whose Haki is stronger?

Comment: I don't think there are really grades per se, it depends more on the power of the Haki user, the more they are stronger, and the more they've trained a certain type of Haki, the stronger their Haki will be

Comment: I inferred that but it seems like there will soon be grading system implemented. It's been brought up twice now once in the Zorro vs Pica fight and again now. That there is a difference in hardness but unless stated by the fighters we can't actually tell if that is the case or not. Do you think there will be a visual distinction added?

Comment: Yes, that might be possible, there is already the more flexible luffy haki in his 4th gear which seems to be taking a different color as far as I can remember. I am not sure though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes perfect sense that Armament Haki can be used at different levels of intensity.  This has already been shown from early on for Observation Haki and Conqueror's Haki.  Enel could sense people over the entire sky island while his men seemed to only see the people they were fighting.  Luffy went from stunning a room with little control to thousands on Fishman island.  The fight betweeen Chinjao and Luffy seemed to indicate that Luffy's won because his Haki was stronger.  This means there are relative levels of power for any of the three types of Haki.

There is, however, no mention in the text of any measurable rating of this strength.

There is, however, a DBZ like powerlevel already in the story.  The CP9 are rated based on Doriki in the Enes Lobby Arc.  A common armed soldier has a 10 Doriki and 500 is superhuman.  Lucci was 4000.  This method explictly only counts physical strength and ignored devil fruit powers.  There is no indication (as it had not yet been introduced) as to how Haki would impact this measurement system.  If the CP9 developed a method to rate their Rokushiki, it seems guarenteed that CP0 has a way to rate Haki. We just don't know anything about it yet.

Comment: Do not forget the first major difference in Armament Haki was when Law cut up Vergo.

Comment: @Arcane that was his Op Op Fruit.

Comment: @kaine Op Op Fruit combined with Haki, no? Otherwise, if it was pure DF power, Vergo's Haki would have cancelled the DF. At least, that's how I understood from Rayleigh's explanation.

Comment: Maybe. We know Haki works on Logia and Luffy but I don't know if it works on all devil fruits.... in any case I left off that case as I did not know if it qualified thanks to it occurring in a "room"